# Debian on TI-Nspire

Tags: debian, boot, usb, dual-boot, calculator

I am following this tutorial: https://ivoah.net/blog/2016/03/20/how-to-install-debian-on-a-ti-nspire/ (I have all of the required items.)

I am using an Acer Chromebook C720, which I dual-booted Debian buster onto, using crouton. I have a TI-Nspire CX II CAS, which I am trying to dual-boot Debian onto with the help of the tutorial I mentioned.

Steps 1 through 5 work fine for me, but when I do `sudo chroot /mnt` in step 6, I get an error:

```
chroot: failed to run command '/bin/bash': Exec format error
```

I read here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/14280/during-a-chroot-attempt-i-got-this-error-chroot-failed-to-run-command-bin But I have no idea where to go from there.

Should I have dual-booted a 32-bit version of Debian buster, rather than the 64-bit version I am running currently?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't have all these tools and gadgets nor am I going to attempt to try this out. I'm currently reading the manpage to finally, after about 10 years of using Ubuntu, understand better what debootstrap actually does when it is involved. **You have to be very careful here**, read and understand the messages that appear on screen. If you have errors you need to check if you have typed the commands correctly and if the system is still in the desired state at this stage. Sounds silly but every `–` should have been `--`.

Comment: Instead of considering to put disclaimers in front of their guides, people should consider using proper code formatting to not have their blogging software convert `--` or `---` to en or em dashes. Or 1920x1080 to 1920×1080. I have come across such things a few times and it's always the problem that the writer of instructions does not test the instructions himself/herself after writing and publishing them. Good luck.

Comment: I actually noticed the errors in the tutorial that you mentioned. When doing steps 1 through 5, I typed ```--``` rather than ```–```.

Answer (score -1):

use 32-bit, that old of a calculator likely uses 32-bit